# A file format writable by python, readable as a Dataframe in Spark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I have python scripts (no Spark here) producing some data files, that I want to be readable easily as Dataframes in a scala/spark application.

What's the best choice ?

Answer (score 1):

If your data doesn't have newlines in then a simple text-based format such as TSV is probably best.

If you need to include binary data then a separated format like protobuf makes sense - anything for which a hadoop InputFormat exists should be fine.